# Nginx, gunicorn, flask cache not updating - solution: restart instance

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn, forwarding, proxypass

I have a server running nginx, gunicorn and flask.

My problem isn't that the usual thing, that forwarding from nginx to gunicorn doesn't happen. My problem is that nginx forwards to my running gunicorn server half the time and to my index.html files in my directory appdirectory/templates the other half. Which is symbolicly linked to var/www/html.

If I delete the index.html file I receive internal server error half the time and my gunicorn server the other half of the times.

If my gunicorn server isn't running I'm only getting the index.html file.

The essentials of my flask app looks like this.

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    #return render_template("index.html")
    return 'hello world!'

def main(argv=None):

    app.run('0.0.0.0')

    return 0 # success

if __name__ == '__main__':
    status = main()
    sys.exit(status)
```

My script in sites-enabled looks like this

```
server {
        listen 80;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 default ssl; # managed by Certbot
    server_name example.com www.example.com;


    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
    }


if ($scheme != "https") {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


# Redirect non-https traffic to https
# if ($scheme != "https") {
#     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
# } # managed by Certbot

}
```

I hope some has an idea when it forwards to two different places and not just my gunicorn server.

Comment: I have spotted two PID processes. Can this be the reason? I have attached an image.
https://imgur.com/a/xG1UB

Or is it maybe a cache problem? I used to serve the index.html file, but wanted to test whether the app was being served and put a return string instead of index.html as the shown above.

I have tried truning off sendfile in nginx.conf, but no luck.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a cache problem, judging from my tests. But I can't seem to solve it. I've restarted my gunicorn server, systemctl nginx and service nginx. No luck :(

Comment: I figured it out, to some degree. Restarting the instance cleared the cache. This isn't a durable solution, but it solves it short term.

Comment: Restarting the droplet fixed the issue on DigitalOcean. I guess its flask-cache problem.